# Visual Studio Code (VSC) local workspace with cloud based locations/drive (folders\files). Possible?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, icloud, directory-structure

Is is possible to have a workspace (in VSC or any IDE) whereby said local project/folder contains 1 more or more sub folders that are cloud based (such as iCloud)?

I have a standard create react app "project" stored locally on my iMac (home) and when I need to use the same files on my work computer (macbook) I have either committed said changes (SourceTree -> remote) or taken copy via USB). Is there a way to sync just "some" folders to iCloud so that they are available from any location? (and also not break git/sourcetree)

Probable easiest to do the whole folder? and ignore \node_modules (like gitignore, nosync) perhaps?

```
my-app\
my-app\node_modules <- not this folder
my-app\public
my-app\src
```

Answer (score 0):

The more I investigate this issue, the more it appears not to be possible in the context above, even using symbolic links and the .nosync file extn. :-(